# Error with JQUERY Button Details with MODAL ---> f.send((a.hasContent && a.data) || null), (jquery.min.js:5407

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with a web application in MVC
I have a button to open the details in a modal, but when doing so I get the following error

The project on localhost works without **[![texto en negrita][1]][1]**problems, but when publishing it on a server for use by other users this problem appeared, opening the jquery link shows me a specific error in a line which is the following

f.send((a.hasContent && a.data) || null),

What could be wrong? Yes, it works on localhost and already published in IIS, it doesn't!!

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Traduce tu pregunta, de lo contrario terminará [cerrada](/help/closed-questions).